# Request Headers and Parameters are Null Every Time In Custom Filter class When The Request Is made By AJAX

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, controller

I am working on a Spring MVC based project. I have made a Filter Class to prevent XSS attack and configured it in web.xml file. The codes are given below.

```
public final class RequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    public RequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        super(servletRequest);
    }

    private static Pattern[] patterns = new Pattern[]{
            // Script fragments
            Pattern.compile("<script>(.*?)</script>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE),
            // src='...'
            Pattern.compile("src[\r\n]*=[\r\n]*\\\'(.*?)\\\'", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL),
            Pattern.compile("src[\r\n]*=[\r\n]*\\\"(.*?)\\\"", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL),
            // lonely script tags
            Pattern.compile("</script>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE),
            Pattern.compile("<script(.*?)>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL),
            // eval(...)
            Pattern.compile("eval\\((.*?)\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL),
            // expression(...)
            Pattern.compile("expression\\((.*?)\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL),
            // javascript:...
            Pattern.compile("javascript:", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE),
            // vbscript:...
            Pattern.compile("vbscript:", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE),
            // onload(...)=...
            Pattern.compile("onload(.*?)=", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL)
    };

    @Override
    public String[] getParameterValues(String parameter) {

        String[] values = super.getParameterValues(parameter);

        if (values == null) {
            return null;
        }

        int count = values.length;
        String[] encodedValues = new String[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            encodedValues[i] = stripXSS(values[i]);
        }
        return encodedValues;
    }

    @Override
    public String getParameter(String parameter) {
        String value = super.getParameter(parameter);
        return stripXSS(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String getHeader(String name) {
        String value = super.getHeader(name);
        return stripXSS(value);
    }

    private String stripXSS(String value) {
        if (value != null) {

            value = value.replaceAll("\0", "");
            for (Pattern scriptPattern : patterns) {
                value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");
            }
        }
        return value;
    }}
```

And Filter implementing class where RequestWrapper class is getting invoked is:

```
public class CrossScriptingFilter implements Filter {
    private FilterConfig filterConfig;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        this.filterConfig = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(new RequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest)request), response);
    }

}
```

and the web.xml configuration:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>XSS</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.CrossScriptingFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>XSS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

But every time I make a request to the server,it shows all the parameters and all the headers are null. Please help me solve this problem.

```
I need to modify this question, that is- I noticed that the Request Headers and Parameters are null when the request is made by ajax or JavaScript. Otherwise its working correctly.
```